# iTextSharp Not Generating Table Border in PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating PDF file using iTextSharp but border is not showing in my PDF file. How can i generate border too with PDF

**Code to generate pdf:**

```
Private Sub GeneratePDFReport(repeaterName As Repeater)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Vasundhara.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        repeaterName.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.[End]()
    End Sub
```

Anyone can help me . How can i show border in my PDF file
my PDF screenshot is attached with this post[image]

Comment: `HTMLWorker` is obsolete. Try the `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: Hello mkl,   XMLWorker not showing in my iTextSharp

Comment: It is distributed separately, cf. http://itextpdf.com/Products/xml-worker

Comment: If your `HTML` includes the deprecated `border` attribute, it **will** work with `HTMLWorker`. E.g. `<table border='1'>`. It's curious why `HTMLWorker` hasn't removed from the source code after all these years....

Comment: hello  kuujinbo, can u give me any demo link or code ..... actually i am beginner i don't understand much better

Comment: @Aman Please don't use `HTMLWorker`, but go to the [official iText(Sharp) web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and read [How to convert HTML to PDF?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-convert-html-pdf) There are plenty of XML Worker examples in the [Q&A section](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/parsing-xml-and-xhtml) and the [examples section](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker). If you are a beginner, you should read the documentation to get a better understanding of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thnx to all for helping me

Comment: @kuujinbo if you look at the source: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.cs then you will see that `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated. Removing from source completely is not possible within `5.x.x` because that would break backwards compatibility. See Semantic Versioning for more information: http://semver.org/

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to button click.

```
    var styles = new StyleSheet();
    styles.LoadTagStyle("body", "border", "1");
    htmlparser.SetStyleSheet(styles);
```